# difference between composer and composer.phar

Tags: composer-php

What is the difference between `composer` and `composer.phar`?

Example:

- `composer install`
- `composer.phar install`

Is there a reason why I keep seeing code writen using `composer.phar` all the time when `composer` does the same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no difference - `composer.phar` is the executable and `composer` can be an alias or symlink for it, depending on the way you've installed composer. As rob006 pointed out, there can be multiple ways to install composer: the official documentation at https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally recommends to move the downloaded PHAR file to `/usr/local/bin/composer` which will make it callable through `composer` for all users of your system.

If you would move the file to another destination, like `/usr/local/bin/composer.phar`, the same composer binary would be available under that different command `composer.phar`.

And finally, if you would not have the chance to install composer globally, you could put it under either name in any local place

Comment: It is not an alias - usually you move PHAR archive to `/usr/local/bin/composer`, so `composer` is actual name of executable.

Comment: Okay, that's another way to phrase it. If you **move** it there, you can only use one of these two commands. If you define an alias, symlink, whatever, you can use both. Will update my answer

Comment: The question is: why would you want to use `composer.phar` if you can use `composer`? If someone is using `composer.phar`, it probably means that he doesn't installed composer globally - https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally